# Show images by categories

Tags: python, django

i want to show images by categories, getting a little error `index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'category_id'` . When i click on category it shows image, which is assigned to this category. It shows categories but when i click on it i get that error

models.py

```
class Image(models.Model):
    title        = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug         = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    category     = models.ForeignKey('Category')
    description  = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    published    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image        = models.ImageField(upload_to="images")

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % self.title


 class Category(models.Model):
    title        = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug         = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=255)

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % self.title
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<category_id>\d+)/$', views.index, name='lists'),
 )
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    context = {'categories': categories}
    return render(request, 'photo/index.html', context)

def lists(request):
    images = Image.objects.all().order_by('title')
    images = Image.objects.filter(published=True)
    context = {'images': images}
    return render(request, 'photo/lists.html', context)
```

index.html

```
<h2>Categories</h2>
{% for category in categories %}
    <ul>    
        <li>
            <a href="/photo/{{ category.id }}/"> {{category.title}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

lists.html

```
<h1>Photos</h1>
<a href="/photo/{{ image.id }}"><img src="{{ image.image.url }}" style="width:200px; height: 200px; float:left;"/></a>
```

Comment: Chnage your url : 
url(r'^(?P<category_id>\d+)/$', views.lists, name='lists'),
and method like def lists(request,category_id):
can you show your models.py code as well.

Comment: cant figure out what to write there

Comment: show your models.py please.

Comment: edited my post at the begining

Comment: please see changes on ANS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

models.py

```
class Image(models.Model):
    title        = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug         = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    category     = models.ForeignKey('Category')
    description  = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    published    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image        = models.ImageField(upload_to="images")

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % self.title


 class Category(models.Model):
    title        = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug         = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=255)

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % self.title
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^photo/(?P<category_id>\d+)/$', views.lists, name='lists'),
 )
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    context = {'categories': categories}
    return render(request, 'photo/index.html', context)

def lists(request,category_id):
    try:
        categories = Category.objects.get(pk = 'category_id')
    except:pass
    images = categories.image_set.all().order_by('title')
    context = {'images': images}
    return render(request, 'photo/lists.html', context)
```

index.html

```
<h2>Categories</h2>
{% for category in categories %}
    <ul>    
        <li>
            <a href="/photo/{{ category.id }}/"> {{category.title}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

lists.html

```
<h1>Photos</h1>
{%for image in images %}
    <a href="#"><img src="{{ image.image.url }}" style="width:200px; height: 200px; float:left;"/></a>
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Page not found . photo/1" does not exist

Comment: (r'^photo/(?P<category_id>\d+)/$', views.lists), try this url.

and change your setting.py file from DEBUG = True 
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, i had to change my urls.py

```
    url(r'^(?P<category_id>\d+)/$', views.lists, name='lists'),
```